# PHP 'is_writable' returning false, although viewing it from the terminal shows 775

Tags: php, apache, terminal, file-permissions

I'm having trouble setting up a development server based off of a clone from our production server. We use a CMS and it seems that some of its scripts are having permissions issues. Trying to get to the bottom of it we've set up a PHP script to test the permissions, as well as gotten into the terminal to compare its findings.

Our test script is as below

```
//try one of the essential folders of the CMS
$path= '[our_base_dir]/html/cms/content'

echo $path.' is'.(!is_writable($path) ? ' NOT' : '').' writable.<br/>';
```

which prints

```
[our_base_dir]/html/cms/content is NOT writable.
```

However, when going into the terminal, I don't see why that would be. Here is the output of that:

```
$ getfacl content
# file: content
# owner: cchapman
# group: cchapman
user::rwx
user:apache:rw-
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

and

```
$ grep 'cchapman' /etc/group
cms:x:510:cchapman,apache
cchapman:x:512:cms,apache
```

I believe the `apache` user is the user that needs to have the write access, and the `cms` and `cchapman` users would just be the file owners depending on how they were created. In any case, all three should be able to read and write each other's files based on the group permissions.

This is the same at the file level as well as the directory level. My only thought is that there is something going wrong with how the Apache user is treated at the file level. Could that be it? Or what else would be giving the different access permissions?

Comment: and the _absolute_ path `/html/cms/content` is correct? correct as in: it's not `./html/cms/content`, and it is the same as `realpath('/html/cms/content');`? because as an absolute path, `/html/cms/content` doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: Also check if apache isn't using `www-data` user

Comment: Did you restart apache after adding it to group cchpman?

Comment: @Marek we did try restarting apache and there didn't seem to be any change

Comment: Check apache's `Group` setting

Comment: @Marek `$ grep 'apache' /etc/group
apache:x:48:
cms:x:510:cchapman,apache
cchapman:x:512:cms,apache`

Comment: I mean in `httpd.conf`, or any loaded conf. There's likely `User apache` setting, there can be also `Group` setting.

Comment: That was it! It appears that we had the incorrect user listed in the httpd.conf. We adjusted that and everything is now working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect my comment is actually the answer, so I'll post it as one:

By calling `is_writable` on the path string `/html/cms/content`, you're checking to see if the *absolute* path `/html/cms/content` is writable or not. I believe what you want is:

```
$path = realpath('./html/cms/content');//note the .
if (is_writable($path))
    printf('"%s" is writable', $path);
```

If the path you're checking really **is** `/html/cms/content`, which to me seems odd (I'd expect `/var/www/base_dir/html/cms/content` or something), then make sure to get the `realpath` (ie: no symlinks and all that). So always call `realpath` (as I've done in the snippet above).

Other than that: You have an `apache` user, that's fine, but are you sure that the script is being executed by that user? `www-data` and `nobody` are quite common, too. Check what user is actually running your code, and make sure that user has the appropriate rights, too.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering the comment. You were correct though, I did paraphrase the path to try to simplify it which I see that I've oversimplified it. I've edited the code in the question from `/html/cms/content` to `'[our_base_dir]/html/cms/content'`

Comment: In regards to checking to see which user is running the script... would `get_current_user()` be the appropriate method to get that? From what I've run so far, that shows the owner of the `test.php` file running the method. In which case it would be `cchapman` which would be the owner of the directories, and therefore definitely writable... But I'm not sure if that's getting the correct thing...

Comment: @cchapman900 You need to use posix functions: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.posix.php

Comment: @cchapman900: using `get_current_user` should be ok, but it's down to how you execute your code. If you run a command-line test script, the current user will be the one running the cli script. Just dump the current user, and use a browser to get the user apache is using (and use `var_dump(exec('whoami'));`, just to be safe)